# Sorting Array based on an arbitrary index

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I know how to sort a Java array of `ints` or `floats` (or other data types).  But what if it was a string array `String[] arr = {}` where the array contained elements like `2x^2`, `4x^4`.  As you can see, there are several indices that have integers, which could be sorted.

The way I would think to sort this is to splice out the number at an index.  Sort those numbers, then map each old index to the new index.

I feel like there is a better way.

The essential question:  *Does a sorting method exist that can sort a string array based on an integer at a certain index of each index?*

If you are wondering, here would be some sample inputs and outputs of an algorithm as such.

```
Array: {"2x^3","2x^0","1x^1"}
Output:{"2x^3","1x^1","2x^0"} // Sorted based on last index
```

Comment: A lot of sorting methods let you provide a comparator, just set that up to "pick apart" your strings.

Comment: Some sample input and desired output might be helpful here.

Comment: @John3136: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static final Comparator<String> myComparator = 
    new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            // split s1 and s2, compare what you need
            // and return the result.
            // e.g.
            // char digit1 = s1[s1.length() - 1];
            // char digit2 = s2[s2.length() - 1];
            // return (int)(digit1 - digit2);
        }
     };

Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
// or
Arrays.sort(array, myComparator);
```

So you are letting someone else's sort method do the sorting for you, you just need to provide a method to say how to compare the items. There are some rules and regulations you need to stick to (e.g. if A < B, B < C then A must be < C).

You can also do it inline/anonymously:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        ...
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer.  I understand most of this, except what gets returned.  Ex.  The last digit of string 1 is higher than the last digit of string 2.  What would be returned?

Comment: Top of my head: I can't remember ;-) It's easy enough to try `digit1 - digit2`, and if that doesn't work then it must be `digit2 - digit1`.